# I want opensource application in C# or VB.net which is similer to MS-Office

Tags: .net, localization

I want to develop a application like MS-Office specially like ms-word and excel. I want opensource application in `vb.net or`C#.net` to which I can extend to ms-word and excel kind of functioning and i will make its language in my regional language to help my regional people to work on computers.

Comment: You're best bet is an online office suite, like Google Docs - http://docs.google.com . I don't know if it's localized, but that would be easier than writhing a whole Office...

Comment: I notice you didn't actually ask a question.

Comment: I totally agree with Vasiliy and Konamiman. The best way of helping would be to use OpenOffice.org, that way you're not Vendor-LockedIn, use Open Standards and you have also the power of whole Office-Suite at your fingertips for no price.

Comment: If the concern on non-.NET platform (e.g. C++/Java) is that you don't know it yet, software like this is complex enough that I think it will take less time and effort for you to learn enough C++ and Java to tailor OpenOffice to your needs than to rebuild its functionality from scratch.

Comment: @Michael: Heh. This reminds, we once had our BA ask us to write a WYSIWYG PDF editor in about 8 hours. We were looking at him, "Do you recognize the complexity of such an application?"

Comment: Difficult to understand what you want. If you develop your own application you can make it OSS. If you just want to find an alternative to MS office the question belongs on another forum.

Comment: I just wants an opensource application to which i can changes some functionality or specially labels.. because lots of people in my region are not good at english. so i was willing to perform some label text changing to make that application easy to use by my regional people...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even ms-word and excel are not written in C#, so why you bother. The best you can get in .NET is syntax coloring editors only, or some kind of HTML editors which you have to extend.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/TextEditorControl.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/AvalonEdit.aspx

Answer (score 3):

The best way for you to help your locacl people is to use OpenOffice.org as it was already said. If there is no translation on your language (but I think there is one) simple help OOo community with one more localization. And you'll get best freeware Office Suite result in the shortest term.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what exactly your question is, but anyway, take a look at [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/). It's open source so you can learn about Office-like application development by looking at its source code.

Comment: i want a open office kind of open source application in vb.net or c#.net so that i can extend it and make more better application.

Comment: @DotNetDeveloper: There is no such thing out there...your best guess is OpenOffice.org, well, it is written in Java, but C# is very, very close to Java.

Comment: Bobby: OOo is not written in Java. It uses some Java, but most of it is written in C++.

Answer (score 1):

I  wanted to do this too so I found a page from openoffice with it's source code.  It's big and I don't know how to edit it.  I also found that it is not very hard to make your own text editor.

- https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/ooo/trunk/
- http://incubator.apache.org/openofficeorg/source.html

Answer (score 0):

Open Office is an Office like implementation. But it is written in C++.

Comment: @Vasiliy Borovyak - It is also using C++. Check this link wikipedia link : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenOffice.org. And look for written in. ;)

Comment: And the macros for scalc aren't written in either language!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you can create extensions to OpenOffice C#+Mono

http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2005/Jun-08.html